# Marketing Cloud - Landing Page updating Data Extensions

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to create a Landing Page with just one button (Unsubscribe) that when is clicked, gets the email of the clicker and searches it in a specific data extension and updates a boolean field to FALSE.

I am trying to do it through a Smart Capture and then an Automation Studio, however, it seems that Automation Studio only works for inserting data, but not updating it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.